# Python - Using a List, Dict Comprehension, and Mapping to Change Plot Order

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, mapping

I am relatively new to Python, Pandas, and plotting.  I am looking to make a custom sort order in a pandas plot using a list, mapping, and sending them through to the plot function.

I am not "solid" on mapping or dict comprehensions.  I've looked around a bit on Google and haven't found anything really clear - so any direction to helpful references would be much appreciated.

I have a dataframe that is the result of a groupby:

```
Exchange
AMEX       267
NYSE      2517
Nasdaq    2747
Name: Symbol, dtype: int64
```

The numerical column is 'Symbol' and the exchange listing is the index

When I do a straightforward pandas plot

```
my_plot = Exchange['Symbol'].plot(kind='bar')
```

I get this:

[image]

The columns are in the order of the rows in the dataframe (Amex, NYSE, Nasdaq) but I would like to present, left to right, NYSE, Nasdaq, and Amex.  So a "sort" won't work.

There is another post:

[Sorting the Order of Bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635110/sorting-the-order-of-bars-in-pandas-matplotlib-bar-plots)

that gets at this - but I just couldn't figure it out.

I feel like the solution is one step out of my reach.  I think this is a very important concept to get down as it would help me considerably in visualizing data where the not-infrequent case of a custom row presentation in a chart is needed.  I'm also hoping discussion here could help me better understand mapping as that seems to be very useful in many instances but I just can't seem to find the right on-line resource to explain it clearly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to your problem is putting your output dataframe into desired order:

```
order = [1,2,0] # the desired order
Exchange['Symbol'].iloc[order]

NYSE      2517
Nasdaq    2747
AMEX       267
Name: Symbol, dtype: int64
```

As soon as you have the rightly ordered data you can plot it:

```
Exchange['Symbol'].iloc[order].plot(kind='bar');
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this - so easy and yet it escaped me.  The real lesson here for me was the use of iloc.  I'm familiar with using it to iterate in two dimensions (e.g., df.iloc[row,column]).  I didn't know I could iterate this way where a column is specified.  Makes it super simple.  Thanks again!