# Sorting and conditional color formatting in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

*to skip the context and get straight to the question, go down to "desired changes"*

I wrote the helper function below to

1. Fetch data
2. Calculate the YTD return
3. Plot the results in a bar plot

Here is the function:

```
def ytd_perf(symb, col_names, source = 'yahoo'):
    import datetime as datetime
    from datetime import date
    import pandas as pd
    import pandas_datareader.data as web
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    %pylab inline

    #establish start and end dates
    start = date(date.today().year, 1, 1)
    end = datetime.date.today()

    #fetch data
    df = web.DataReader(symb, source, start = start, end = end)['Adj Close']

    #make sure column orders don't change
    df = df.reindex_axis(symb, 1)

    #rename the columns
    df.columns = col_names

    #calc returns from the first element
    df = (df / df.ix[0]) - 1

    #Plot the most recent line of data -- this represents the YTD return
    ax = df.ix[-1].plot(kind = 'bar', title = ('YTD Performance as of '+ str(end)),figsize=(12,9))
    vals = ax.get_yticks()
    ax.set_yticklabels(['{:3.1f}%'.format(x*100) for x in vals])
```

So, when I run:

```
tickers = ['SPY', 'TLT']
names = ['Stocks', 'Bonds']

ytd_perf(tickers, names)
```

I get the following output:
[image]

2 **desired changes** that I can't quite get to work:

1. I would like to change the color of the bar such that if the value < 0, it is red.
2. Sort the bars from highest to lowest (which is the case in this chart because there are only two series, but doesnt work with many series).

Comment: Change 1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22311139/matplotlib-bar-chart-choose-color-if-value-is-postive-vs-value-is-negative

Comment: Change 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635110/sorting-the-order-of-bars-in-pandas-matplotlib-bar-plots