# How to plot a bar graph labels in alphabetical order in python?

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, alphabetical

I have the following bar graph:

[Click here for bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9aol.png)

I would like to alphabetically order the Y-axis labels (i.e, control, exclude, necrosis, other, tissue, tumor and not control, other, necrosis, exclude, tissue, tumor). Ho do I do that?

What I tried so far?

```
smack = df.roi_name.value_counts()

plt.barh(width=smack.values, y=smack.index)
plt.xlim(0,50000)
plt.xlabel("ROI_NAME count")
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried sorting all of it before plotting?

Comment: You can find solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635110/sorting-the-order-of-bars-in-pandas-matplotlib-bar-plots

Comment: Yes, doesn`t work. I still get the same bar chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to sort index of your dataframe when you give it to `plt.barh()`, like below:

```
plt.barh(width=smack.values, y=smack.index.sort_values())
```

Comment: you can aslo rearrange index of your dataframe before plotting, and then plot it, like below:
`df = df.sort_index()` 
`plt.barh(width=smack.values, y=smack.index.)`